# Powershell: Is disposing of an SPWeb object necissary when its referenced from an SPSIte object?

Tags: powershell

**Edit** This is for SharePoint 2007

I have this powershell script:

```
## Reference to SharePoint DLL 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c”) 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c”)
## Probable location of sharepoint STSADM utility program 
$stsadm = "$env:programfiles\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN\STSADM.EXE" 

############################################ 
# Activate-feature-onSite [-feature  |-url  ] 
############################################ 
$spsite=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]("site-url"); 

foreach($web in $spsite.AllWebs)
{
  $websiteurl= $web.url
  $sResult = &stsadm -o deactivatefeature -id '6C45F6A6-17CC-49f4-A30F-4424C7DF3563' -url $websiteurl -force
  if(!($sResult -like "*Operation completed successfully*")){ 
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor "red" -BackgroundColor "white" "Deactivation of feature ‘’ for ‘$websiteurl’ Failed!" 
 } 
 else{
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor "blue" -BackgroundColor "white" "Deactivation of feature 6C45F6A6-17CC-49f4-A30F-4424C7DF3563 for ‘$websiteurl’ Worked! `n $sResult" 
 }
} 
$spsite.Dispose()
```

And before it is deployed id like to run it by some pros and see if I am correctly disposing of the site, and if i should dispose of the webs aswell.

Ive never used powershell before, so im not sure if it follows the regular disposal practices, or if it does the disposal itself, etc.

Any feedback would be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this answer:

[How bad is it to not dispose() in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999858/how-bad-is-it-to-not-dispose-in-powershell/2001729#2001729)

> When you close the PowerShell.exe process, the memory is freed. If you
>   need to dispose objects to keep memory pressure down (important in
>   production environments or if you're looping over all sites/webs),
>   make sure to dispose. If not, you don't need to worry about disposing.

In your case `$spsite.Dispose()` doesn't do anything because it is last command in your script so memory will be freed when script ends.

Comment: What about the SPWeb objects? This script is going to be run multiple times.

Comment: It does matter only if number of webs on your site is huge, really huge. So by using `$web.Dispose()` in your foreach loop you can save some memory. It doesn't cost you anything to put that extra line :)

Comment: Yea, there are a couple hundred webs in the biggest site collection so it will definitely help.